# Eliminating duplicate rows in DataTables.net

Tags: datatables

Context: I have a web worker that "subscribes" to data updates from the back end via a websocket, which are then published to a view rendered via DataTables.net To increase efficiency, added data is pushed down the websocket as a partial record (ie. one row only).

Since the data is decoupled from the DataTable (ie. it's not using the Ajax API; it's basically a JavaScript source), I cannot just add the row and render the table. In the event that two pushes of the same row are triggered, I end up with duplicate rows.

So, I whipped up a little plugin:

```javascript
$.fn.dataTable.Api.register('deDupe', function (dataSet, idColumn) {
  idColumn = idColumn || 0;
  var columnData = this.columns().data()[idColumn];

  for(var i=0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
    var thisId = dataSet[i].id;
    var matchedIndex = columnData.indexOf(thisId);
    if(matchedIndex > -1) {
      var matchedRow = $(this.rows().nodes()[matchedIndex]);
      this.row(matchedRow).remove();
    }
  }

  // return "this" for chaining
  return this;
});
```

(Don't laugh at me for taking comfort in old fashioned "for" loops!)

And then in usage, I do this:

```
myTable.deDupe(dataSet).rows.add(dataSet).draw();
```

The method that receives the data and then updates the table already has the incoming row, which is contained in "dataSet", and then I pass a COLUMN index for the column which is meant to contain the unique ID for de-duping purposes. Note that in code execution, rather than dropping an incoming duplicate, I am removing the previous row, then adding the incoming one. There are cases where the row contains updated data, and I really only care about de-duping at the ID level, not the contents level... always just blindly use the latest data.

So a few questions:

1. Is there a better way of doing this? I would've loved to see a core option, but I didn't come across one. It seems like relatively common functionality. Am I crazy here, re-inventing the wheel? (in other words, an initialization option?)
2. In the conditional checking if there's a match, you see this line: `var matchedRow = $(this.rows().nodes()[matchedIndex]);` This strikes me as wacky, but I couldn't get my head around the other ways of identifying a row to be used in the `.remove()` chain. In my mind, I already know the index of the row, so I thought something like `matchedRow = this.rows(matchedIndex)` would work, but I can't find that or something similar. So not only am I digging into `rows().nodes()` but then the whole thing is wrapped up in jQuery before then being passed into `.row(matchedRow)`'. It seems so heavily nested and wrapped for something I feel like I should already have direct access to.

Don't get me wrong; the code "works" and fixing it is probably a micro-optimization. But it strikes me as awfully convoluted and gives me some code smell, which I want to avoid for the sake of maintenance developers.

Comment: Honestly I think the code is fine for the most part - the only thing I would add is a `break;` after `this.row(matchedRow).remove();`, unless you think you'll potentially have more than one duplicate row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, this may be a micro-optimization, but an option may be to select all of the rows and remove them en toto.

```
$.fn.dataTable.Api.register('deDupe', function (dataSet, idColumn) {

  idColumn = idColumn || 0;

  // Get the possible dataSet ids into an array for easier lookup
  var dsIds = dataSet.map( (d) => d.id );

  // Use a function in the rows() API to obtain all rows with
  // a value in the idColumn that matches one of the incoming
  // ids on the dataSet
  var matchedRows = this.rows( (i,r) => dsIds.indexOf(r[idColumn]) > -1 );

  // Remove all of the rows at once (this could be chained to the selector above)
  matchedRows.remove();

  // return "this" for chaining
  return this;
});
```

See [row-selector:Function reference](https://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector#Function)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Forty! The question boiled down to "can I make this more efficient?" and I think this answer meets that criteria.

Comment: It needed a slight tweak: my assumption for idColumn is that by default I wanted to correlate the numerical index (zero) of the visible columns to whatever its actual named value is. Then column zero could have data named "id" or "name" or whatever, and it would still work. But it's overly engineered and overly fussy, I think. I can either just pass in what the ID should be, or assume the key "id" by default. Short version: I am not looking for matches in r[idColumn] (by default, r[0]), I am looking for matches in r[idKey] (for one sample table, r["id"] for example.

Comment: addendum to above: I have a bad habit of wanting to allow default values. If the method explicitly requires an "idKey" parameter (not even bothering with the `idKey = idKey || "id";` pattern), I would probably be a happier man with more easily-maintained code.